# How would a weightless object behave on earth?

Tags: classical-mechanics, gravity, buoyancy, weight

DISCLAIMER: Bear in mind that I am a mere 11th-grader:

It came to me that an object with a net zero pounds (on earth) might sit more-or-less statically in the air.

An example might be a ball of hydrogen sporting a jacket of heavy, non-static urethane...

Anyway: I figured that if the masses of the materials perfectly canceled the other out, the ball would sit in the air -- barring wind and such like -- where it was positioned. I *obviously* do not mean an object of zero *mass*; that would open up all kinds of relativity stuff. Therefore, it would also have inertia. Interesting...

But then I thought, "Wait, the atmosphere becomes less and less dense as you ascend. The object would become lighter and lighter as it moved UpwardSoMaybeItWouldn'tActHowIThoughtItWouldAtAll! Maybe I have no clue!"

I rectified this problem theoretically by making the urethane *slightly* heavier than the hydrogen. so maybe it would work, or maybe it would s l o w l y  s i n k  t o  t h e  g r o u n d ...

What do you think? How would it act, theoretically, yet practically speaking?
(And I don't want an answer that includes spherical cows in a vacuum.)

Answer (score 2):

Just think of a helium party balloon.  If you add bits of paper you can get it to float stationary in the air.  In this case the weight of the rubber balloon is offset by the weight of the helium gas.

The behavior is quite simple, it floats stationary but will move with the slightest puff of wind.

But don't think of mass in this case, think of weight.  Mass is the same everywhere and on every planet. But weight is different on every planet. So a balloon that floats stationary on Earth would still rise higher on the moon.

If a balloon has more helium in it, it will rise up in the air until it eventually reaches an equalization pressure and won't rise any higher.
[image: rising up!]

As a balloon rises, it expands to equalize out the pressure. This is why weather balloons look empty when they are near the ground but get much larger when they are high in the air.  They are designed to withstand this growth.

Answer (score 2):

No object with non-zero mass is weightless. What you appear to be talking about is an object that has the same density as air, which will float in the air. Since the density of the air decreases with height, on average, the object would float at the height at which its density exactly matched that of the air. In practice the position would be unstable, as air pressure is variable.

Comment: ah, an equilibrium-buoyancy or something? now i'm starting to wonder if just enough weight could be added to it that it would sink at a desired rate from a specific height.
Anyway, thank you for your concise and informative answer!

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're a new contributor, so welcome to PSE!

With regards to your question, I am not sure if I understand the question, because mass and weight are related on Earth by the gravitational constant. So I don't think it's possible to have something that weighs nothing but has nonzero mass.

With regards to hydrogen in urethane, both have positive mass so have positive weight on Earth. Maybe you mean that an air tunnel scenario, in which case a weight, which naturally wants to fall towards Earth, is propped up by air pushing it in the other direction. But even in this case the weight has positive weight, but it is just not falling because there is an external force counteracting the force of gravity.